# How to let the page reload specify div in RoR?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I modify my RoR application to calling a create.js.rjs after created an item. I want to reload a specify div in my page after I create an item, how can I do that?

When my div have a ruby object like this:

```
<div id="categoryList">
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <%= content_tag(:dt, category.name, :class => "menu-table")%><%= link_to 'X', category, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
    <%category.products.each do |product| %>
        <%= content_tag(:dd, product.title, :class => "menu-table")%><%= link_to 'X', product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

how can I pass the ruby object to this then reload the specific page again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target it using an id tag.

for example in your view

```
<div id="my-div"> Replace this content </div>
```

Then in your rjs file

```
page.replace_html("my-div", "Your updated content");
```

When you are using Ajax, I would recommend giving each div or element that you plan on interacting with a unique id so that you can target them from Javascript.

Good luck!  If you need anything else just let me know,

Thanks,

Kent